# Error using patch in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-gui

I am creating a drag box to zoom in that uses the `patch` function. I get the following error when I drag:

```
Error using patch
Not enough input arguments.

Error in boxReady (line 31)
guiele.dragBox = patch(guiele.ResponsePlotAxis, ...
                       repmat(vabls.CurrentPoint(1,1),[1 4]), ...
                       repmat(vabls.CurrentPoint(1,2),[1 4]));
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
% This is the point the cursor is at when the user presses down. drawBox is called again
% when the button is released and the current point then is the other corner of the patch
vabls.CurrentPoint = get(guiele.ResponsePlotAxis,'CurrentPoint');

set(guiele.ResponsePlotLine,'erasemode','none');

XYLims=[get(guiele.ResponsePlotAxis,'xlim') get(guiele.ResponsePlotAxis,'ylim')];

axes(guiele.ResponsePlotAxis);
hold on;
if ishandle(guiele.dragBox)
    delete(guiele.dragBox);
end
guiele.dragBox = patch(guiele.ResponsePlotAxis, ...
                       repmat(vabls.CurrentPoint(1,1),[1 4]), ...
                       repmat(vabls.CurrentPoint(1,2),[1 4]));
set(guiele.dragBox,'FaceColor','none','EdgeColor','r','LineStyle',':');

% initialize some varaiables
guiele.ResponsePlotAxis=-1;
guiele.dragBox = -1;
```

Comment: You aren't giving `patch` enough inputs. Check the help page for `patch` against the inputs you are giving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The three-argument form for [`patch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html) (or 4-argument form including an axes handle) requires that you also enter [color data](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html#inputarg_C) for each patch:

```
patch(X, Y, C);
% Or ...
patch(ax, X, Y, C);
```

If you don't want to enter color data, you can use the following form:

```
patch(ax, 'XData', X, 'YData', Y);
```

So your call to `patch` would look something like this:

```
guiele.dragBox = patch(guiele.ResponsePlotAxis, ...
                       'XData', repmat(vabls.CurrentPoint(1, 1), [1 4]), ...
                       'YData', repmat(vabls.CurrentPoint(1, 2), [1 4]));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am very new to this website and so far I have learnt so much from you.